# Running Vue JS project in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, frontend

I have already built a few VueJs applications for myself. Now I am working with a team. One backend and me frontend.

Now I'm wondering how do I include the environment in the repository.  Until today I always had node on my local machine. With nvm I could also jump between versions on the local machine. But now I want future colleagues who will develop the app to have the same environment. So work with the same node and npm version. I thought this could be done with a dockerfile or docker-compose.yml. Then I can log into the container and run the npm run build for example.

**Question** But how does it work with `npm run dev`? Do I have access with the browser to the port that is assigned in the container of the Vue app?

Comment: Are you using vue 2 or vue 3?

Comment: @AnonymousUser I use Vue 3.